# How can I select specific columns from a joined table in Knex.js?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I have worked about 20 years with SQL databases and seem to have trouble understanding Knex way to map queries.  Can someone help me get the correct code?

I have this SQL query that I want to use in my nodejs application:

```
SELECT p.id, p.project_number, p.project_name, p.start_date, p.end_date,
   o.name, o.email_addr,
   c.company, c.email_addr AS company_email, c.first_name, c.last_name
FROM projects p
INNER JOIN owners o ON o.id = p.owner_id
INNER JOIN clients c ON c.id = p.client_id
```

KnexJS (0.7.5) documentation shows example that would look like this for my query:

```
knex.from('projects').innerJoin('owners', 'owners.id', 'projects.owner_id')
  .innerJoin('clients', 'clients.id', 'projects.client_id');
```

There are couple of things I cannot find in the documentation:

1) how do I select which columns I want to include? Projects, Clients and Owners each have 20 to 50 columns and I am not interested in all of them.  Selecting columns from the main table is clear (using **select()** or **column()** ) but how to select columns from the joined tables?

2) Some columns have identical names.  How can I avoid name conflicts (i.e. add some prefix to columns from other tables)?  I looked at the way Knex can generate column aliases (... AS ...) and I am not sure it is a viable option for more complex queries. (Even for relatively simple queries like the one above)

Answer (score 13):

You can try:

```
knex('projects').select(['projects.id', 'projects.project_number', 'projects.project_name', 'projects.start_date', 'projects.end_date',
    'owners.name', 'owners.email_addr as owner_email_addr',
    'clients.company', 'clients.email_addr as client_email_addr', 'clients.first_name', 'clients.last_name'])
.innerJoin('owners', 'owners.id', 'projects.owner_id')
.innerJoin('clients', 'clients.id', 'projects.client_id');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

In this answer i will cover more then just selecting and the question itself !

## selecting and avoiding name conflicts

The principle to select would be to use `select`. And name conflicts can be avoided by renaming the columns (aliasing).
And to create aliases (column renaming) just use `as` within the column name string as in the snippet bellow:

```
knex
.select([
    'table_a.id',
    'table_b.id as b_id'  // --->  the way to create aliases (to avoid 
])                             //  columns overlapping and overriding
.from('table_a')
.leftJoin(
    'table_b',
    'table_a.table_b_id',
    'table_b.id'
);
```

It will produce this SQL:

```
SELECT 
  "table_a"."id",
  "table_b"."id" as "b_id"
FROM 
  "table_a" 
LEFT JOIN "table_b" ON 
  "table_a"."table_b_id" = "table_b"."id"
```

We can formulate in different ways. Some interesting ones are as in bellow:

```
knex('processes') // <-- wihtout using from (shorter) [less sql like though]
.select([ 
    'processes.id as processId',
    'processes.name as processName',
    'processes.description as processDescription',
    'processes.deleted as processDeleted',
    'processes.deleteTime as processDeleteTime',
    'rsp.runningSettingId',
    'rsp.value as settingValue',
    'rsp.startTime as settingStartTime'
])
.innerJoin(
   'runningSettings_processes as rsp',
   'processes.id',
   'rsp.processId'
);
```

#### Multiple joins examples (3 and more)

```
const superJoinData = await knex( // i'm using async await for the promises
        knex<Process>('process')//__________________________from here
        .select([
            'processes.id as processId',
            'processes.name as processName', //--- conflict with rs.name
            'processes.description as processDescription', //-- conflict with rs.description
            'processes.deleted as processDeleted',
            'processes.deleteTime as processDeleteTime',
            'rsp.runningSettingId',
            'rsp.value as settingValue',
            'rsp.startTime as settingStartTime'
        ])
        .innerJoin(
            'runningSettings_processes as rsp',
            'processes.id',
            'rsp.processId'
        )//_______________________to here 
        .as('prsp') //            |first join. (result an equivalent of a table)
    ) // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! notice how we nested a knex construct within another!!
    .select([ // select from the resulting table of the first join !!!!
        'prsp.processId',
        'prsp.processName',
        'prsp.processDescription',
        'prsp.processDeleted',
        'prsp.processDeleteTime',
        'prsp.runningSettingId',
        'prsp.settingValue',
        'prsp.settingStartTime',
        'rs.name as settingName',
        'rs.description as settingDescription'
    ])
    .innerJoin( // ______________second inner join
        'runningSettings as rs',
        'prsp.runningSettingId',
        'rs.id'
    );
```

> Notice how to use `as()` method!

## extra (unrelated to select, but constructs and join)

Filtering with where:

```
knex(
  knex('A').where('A.id',1).as('t1')
).leftJoin(
  knex('B').where('B.id', 2).as('t2'), 
  't1.c', 
  't2.d'
)

//or filter the resulting table of the join
knex('A')
.leftJoin(
  knex('B').where('B.id', 2).as('t2'), 
  't1.c', 
  't2.d'
)
.where('someColumn', 2);
```

Using callbacks for further control

```
knex
.select('*')
.from(function () {
     this.select('*').from('A')
     .where('id',1)
     .as('t1');
})
.leftJoin(
     knex('B').where('id',2).as('t2'), 
     function () {
          this.on('t1.c', '=', 't2.d'); // <--- notice also the use of function 
     }                                        // construct for the join condition
);
```

Same as above without function construct (and with multiple join conditions as a bonus)

```
knex( // <--- notice the knex constructor (equivTo: knex.select().from())
      knex('A')   //NT: we already used that above when answering the question 
      .select('*')
     .where('id',1)
     .as('t1'); 
)
.leftJoin(
     knex('B').where('id',2).as('t2'), 
     function () { // <----- notice that in place of using the 2nd and 3d arg, we can have a function in the 2nd arg
          this.on('t1.c', '=', 't2.d').on('t1.s', '=', 't2.g'); // <-----| 
     }                             // plus: multiple on conditions______/
);
```

Comment: solution using knex it worked for me , great!!

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to select all columns from one table, and specific columns from another table, you can use:

```
knex('projects').select(['projects.*', 'owners.email_addr as owner_email_addr', 'clients.email_addr as client_email_addr', 'clients.first_name', 'clients.last_name'])
.innerJoin('owners', 'owners.id', 'projects.owner_id')
.innerJoin('clients', 'clients.id', 'projects.client_id');
```

Which will grab all of the columns from `projects`, one column from `owners`, and three from `clients`.